# using javascript to play audio just on iPad

Tags: javascript

Rather than repeat a long javascript for playing audio, here is the link: [webpages.charter.net/jolove/Includes/play_song.js](http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Includes/play_song.js):.

This plays for any desktop browser (Mac or Windows), but not for my iPad.

Here is the calling website: webpages.charter.net/jolove/Escort_Folder/Dedication_Poem_iOS.html

This is really bugging me, so I would definitely appreciate any help on this, any help at all.

John Love

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your question is, but you can use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag which is supported by the iPad.  Check out http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/audio.php or just google "HTML5 audio".

Comment: The above play_song.js code works dandy on every Mac and Windows browser that I have access to; but it will only show as an "X" on the iPad.

Comment: One more thing before I forget.  In googling "javascript audio ipad", I am getting the strangest tingling that iPad does not support playing such formats as midi, wav and perhaps others.  All this sounds very, very bizarre, but it's what I have read so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost forced to conclude that iPad will not play audio files.

Here is a very fresh [site](http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Escort_Folder/God_Bless_the_USA.html), where I use 
the audio.  
But, this time, I got a button that says "cannot play audio file".  For the sake of completeness, here is the included `webpages.charter.net/jolove/Escort_Folder/js/play_song.js`